# Unity Erase Image from mouse pointer

Tags: unity, unityscript

I want to erase the image for mouse pointer in unity. My pointer should be as a eraser. What is I do create the eraser? My sprite is always change because it provide from the server. Please help me.

Comment: you would need to get the mouse pointer in relation to the image, and delete/return to transparancy colour the image in the size/shape you want.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [previous questions about painting in Unity to get some ideas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/102131/39518)? What have you tried so far based on your research? And are you really using the deprecated language UnityScript as you've tagged this question, or would you prefer to work in Unity's more commonly used C# API?